# I am not able to understand how this expression for limit of rational functions has been obtained

Tags: limits

Under the discussion of limits of polynomials and rational functions, rational functions are being discussed. Here they have said that a function f is said to be a rational function

*f(x)* = *g(x)*/*h(x)*,

*$\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$* = *$\lim_{x \to a} [g(x)/h(x)]$* where *g(x)* and *h(x)* are polynomials such that *h(x)* ≠ 0.

Then *f(x)* = *g(a)*/*h(a)*

I'm able to understand up till this part but the next part is where I'm confused.

They're talking about two cases if *h(a)* = 0, if *g(a)* ≠ 0 then limit does not exist. And if *g(a)* = 0, then the limit exists. (I guess because even though the limit of *h(x)* and *g(x)* might be individually 0, the limit of *f(x)* can still be obtained by manipulating the fraction right?)

Now, we can write *g(x)* = *$(x-a)^k g_1(x)$*, where k is the maximum of powers of *(x-a)* in *g(x)*. Similarly for *h(x)* = *$(x-a)^1 h_1(x)$* and if k > l,

*$\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$* = *$\lim_{x \to a} (x-a)^kg_1(x)$*/*$\lim_{x \to a} (x-a)^1h_1(x)$*

= 0.*$g_1(a)$*/*$h_1(a)$* = 0. And if k < l, the limit is not defined.

I am unable to understand this last part. I think *$g_1(x)$* and *$h_1(x)$* might be some function which when multiplied to $(x-a)^k$ and $(x-a)$ returns g(x) and h(x) but apart from this I do not understand how is k and l related here and I assume we've taken (x-a) because that's the part responsible for making the numerator and denominator 0 and we need to get rid of them to obtain the limit of f(x), right?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the polynomials, you can write

$$g(x)=(x-a)^kg_1(x),\\h(x)=(x-a)^lh_1(x)$$
 where $g_1(a)$ and $h_1(a)$ take a nonzero value. $k,l$ are non-negative integers and are uniquely defined (they are the multiplicities of the roots at $a$, possibly $0$).

Then $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{(x-a)^{k}}{(x-a)^{l}}\lim_{x\to a}\frac{g_1(x)}{h_1(x)}=\ \lim_{x\to a}(x-a)^{k-l}\frac{g_1(a)}{h_1(a)}.$$
This makes a much simpler discussion, depending only on the sign of $k-l$

Answer (score 0):

[formatting adjusted and missing "$^l$" included in one place]

> I think $g_1(x)$ and $h_1(x)$ might be some function which when multiplied to $(x−a)^k$ and $(x−a)^l$ returns $g(x)$ and $h(x)$...

That's exactly right. When you have a polynomial $p(x)$, and a linear term $x-a$, you can do polynomial division with remainder $p(x) = q(x)(x-a)+r$. Since the degree of the divisor $x-a$ is $1$, the remainder is of lesser degree, so a constant $r$.

Now note that when the discussion has arrived at that point, we already assume $g(a)=0, h(a)=0$. So if we apply the above to $p(x)=g(x)$, we get $g(x)=q_g(x)(x-a)+r$.

If you substitute $x=a$ on the left side, you get $g(a)=0$, if you subsitute it on the right side, you get $q_g(a)(a-a)+r=r$. This means $r=0$ and thus $g(x)=q_g(x)(x-a)$. You can continue this process now with $p(x)=q_g(x)$. If $q_g(a) \neq 0$ you are done. If $q_q(a)=0$, you get $q_g(x)=q_{g_2}(x)(x-a)$, from which follows $g(x)=q_{g_2}(x)(x-a)^2$.

You continue to do this process until finally $q_{g_k}(a) \neq 0$ (this process must stop, as each quotient has one degree less than the previous). So you get (where your books just uses $g_1(x)$ instead of my $q_{g_k}(x)$)

$$g(x)=q_{g_k}(x)(x-a)^k, \text{where }q_{g_k}(a) \neq 0.$$

The same can be done for $h(x)$. The number of steps until the quotient is not zero at $x=a$ can be different, so we denote it by $l$ and we get analogously:

$$h(x)=q_{h_l}(x)(x-a)^l, \text{where }q_{h_h}(a) \neq 0.$$

> I do not understand how is k and l related

They are not related a priori. $k$ is determined purly by the properties of $g(x)$ and $l$ purely by $h(x)$. But which is greater determines if the limit will tend to $0$, $\infty$ or a non-zero real number.

> I assume we've taken (x-a) because that's the part responsible for making the numerator and denominator 0

Bingo! $x-a$ is the term that caues $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ to tend to zero near $x=a$. The degree of $(x-a)$ in them determines if the enumerator or denominator goes to zero faster.

We have

$$f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{h(x)} = \frac{g_1(x)(x-a)^k}{h_1(x)(x-a)^l}= \frac{(x-a)^k}{(x-a)^l}\frac{g_1(x)}{h_1(x)} = (x-a)^{k-l} \frac{g_1(x)}{h_1(x)}$$

Note that by construction, we have $g_1(a)\neq 0, h_1(a)\neq 0$, so the term $\frac{g_1(x)}{h_1(x)}$ is not making problems when using the limit $x \to a$, it will tend to the non-zero number $\frac{g_1(a)}{h_1(a)}$. The 'interesting' part of the limit is $(x-a)^{k-l}$, which will tend to $0$ if $k > l$, $1$ if $k=l$ and $\infty$ if $k<l$.